# Passing arbitrary options to rabl partial/extend

Tags: ruby, rabl

Is it possible to pass options other than the object into a rabl partial?

For example, the parent template passes an option called "show_field1" to the base template:

```
extends "base", :show_field1 => true
```

Then in base.rabl the option could be used like this:

```
attribute :field1 if @show_field1
```

The only way I've been able to get at the option is through this terrible approach of looking under the covers:

```
attribute :field1 if @_options[:show_field1]
```

Comment: did you find a more eloguent way of doing this?

Comment: I ended up implementing a :locals argument for extends like erb templates use, I haven't made a pull-request yet however: https://github.com/bloomfire/rabl/compare/master...bloomfire

Answer (score 1):

RABL supports this by using a special `locals` Hash:

```
# some_view.rabl
extends "base", locals: { show_field1: true }

# base.rabl
attribute :field1 if locals[:show_field1]
```

[RABL Documentation on the subject](https://github.com/nesquena/rabl#passing-locals-in-partials)

Answer (score 0):

another way would be to store those values on the top level object and have the extend pick it up in the template.

Thanks for the recco @achiu